# How to improve speed on my laravel website?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, optimization

I built a website using Laravel and it's extremely slow.

This the code and the files for the website:

**web.php**:

```
Route::get('/product/{url}', 'FrontendController@getProduct')->where('url', '^[\w.-]*$');
```

**FrontendController:**

```
    public function getProduct(String $url){
    $product = Product::where('url', $url)->first();
    $imgs = ProductImage::all()->where('product_id',$product->id);
    return view('frontend.product', ['product' => $product, 'products' => Product::all(), 'images' => $imgs ]);
}
```

**product.blade.php**:

```
   <div class="container-fluid display-products-desktop px-5" style="margin-top:15rem">
    <div class="row mx-0 row-filters-desktop">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end mb-5">
            <a href="" class="cta-links cta-talk-designer" style="padding-right: 5rem">TALK WITH A DESIGNER</a>
            <!-- HOURS CONDITION -->
            @php
            $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Portugal'));
            @endphp

            @if ($dt->format('H:i:s') >= '09:00:00' && $dt->format('H:i:s') <= '18:00:00')
                <a class="cta-links" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-five-minutes-modal">CALL ME IN 5 MINUTES</a>
            @else
                <a class="cta-links" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-us-modal">CONTACT US</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-2 p-0 thumb-div" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.8);">
            <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs m-0">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    @foreach ($images as $image)
                    <div class="swiper-slide thumbs"><img src="{{ $image->url }}" alt="" class="gallery-thumbs-slide"></div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
            <div class="swiper-container gallery-top m-0">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    @foreach ($images as $image)
                    <div class="swiper-slide top"><img src="{{ $image->url }}" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>                
                <div class="swiper-next-2 swiper-dark"></div>
                <div class="swiper-prev-2 swiper-dark"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 p-0 margin-top-text" style="padding-left: 1.5rem !important">
            <p class="product-page-pre-title">meet</p>
            <h1 class="m-0 main-product-title" style="font-weight: 500">{{ $product->name }}</h1>
            <h4 class="mb-5" style="font-weight: 500">by {{ $product->brand }}</h4>
            <p class="paragraph-product-page">{{ $product->description }}</p>
            <h5 class="mt-5 section-title-product-page">MATERIAL AND FINISHES:</h5>
            <p class="paragraph-product-page">{{ $product->finishes }}</p>
            <h5 class="mt-4 section-title-product-page">DIMENSIONS</h5>
            <p class="paragraph-product-page m-0">{{ $product->dimensions }}</p>
            <a class="cta-links" style="margin-top:2.5rem;margin-bottom:2.5rem; display:block;" href="#downloadCatalogue" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#downloadCatalogue">DOWNLOAD CATALOGUE</a>
            <a class="cta-links" style="margin-top:2.5rem;margin-bottom:2.5rem; display:block;" href="#productSheet{{ $product->id}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#productSheet{{ $product->id}}">DOWNLOAD PRODUCT SHEET</a>
            <a class="cta-links" style="margin-top:2.5rem;margin-bottom:2.5rem; display:block;" href="#reqCustom{{ $product->id}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reqCustom{{ $product->id}}">REQUEST CUSTOMIZATION</a>
            <button class="product-price-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPrice{{ $product->id }}">GET PRICE</button>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row mx-0">
        <div class="col-12 p-0 text-center" style="margin-top:6rem">
            <h1 class="m-5" style="font-weight: 600">Related Products</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-row d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <img src="{{ $product->related_product_img_1}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <img src="{{ $product->related_product_img_2}}"  alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <img src="{{ $product->related_product_img_3}}"  alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <img src="{{ $product->related_product_img_4}}"  alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-row d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 5rem">
        @php
            $slug_1 = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->related_product_name_1);
            $url_1 = strtolower( $slug_1 );
            $slug_2 = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->related_product_name_2);
            $url_2 = strtolower( $slug_2 );
            $slug_3 = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->related_product_name_3);
            $url_3 = strtolower( $slug_3 );
            $slug_4 = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->related_product_name_4);
            $url_4 = strtolower( $slug_4 );
        @endphp
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <div class="text-center mt-1">
                <p class="product-subtitle">new</p>
                <a href="/product/{{ $url_1 }}"><h4 class="product-title">{{ $product->related_product_name_1}}</h4></a>
                <a class="product-price-link" href="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_1}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_1}}">get price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
            <div class="text-center mt-1">
                <p class="product-subtitle">new</p>
                <a href="/product/{{ $url_2 }}"><h4 class="product-title">{{ $product->related_product_name_2}}</h4></a>
                <a class="product-price-link" href="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_2}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_2}}">get price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pr-0 pl-1">
            <div class="text-center mt-1">
                <p class="product-subtitle">new</p>
                <a href="/product/{{ $url_3 }}"><h4 class="product-title">{{ $product->related_product_name_3}}</h4></a>
                <a class="product-price-link" href="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_3}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_3}}">get price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="text-center mt-1">
                <p class="product-subtitle">new</p>
                <a href="/product/{{ $url_4 }}"><h4 class="product-title">{{ $product->related_product_name_4}}</h4></a>
                <a class="product-price-link" href="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_4}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPrice{{ $product->related_product_id_4}}">get price</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the results shown on a speed test website:

[image]

[image]

I am a beginner, so I´ve been studying ways to improve this. Do any of you have suggestions on how to improve the website performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question includes a screenshot with five different areas to focus on. Do those.

Comment: Of course. I was just trying to maybe get more suggestions from experience developers regarding the issue as I am studying.

Comment: Instead of us guessing what else there can be (if anything), start by solving the issues you've already know about. If the issue remains after that, come back and ask for additional help. You will then need to do more debugging. Is it the web server that's slow? Network connection? CPU? High traffic? Low on memory? Database queries? There are plenty of different things that can cause performance issues.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by changing the following code and removing a few bootstrap modals from the product.blade.

**FrontEndController:**

```
public function getProductTest(String $url){
    $product = Product::where('url', $url)->first();
    $imgs = ProductImage::where('product_id',$product->id)->get();
    return view('frontend.product-test', ['product' => $product, 'images' => $imgs ]);
}
```

The speed went from almost eleven seconds to 1.22 seconds.

Comment: You should use route model binding and eager loading instead of doing lookups yourself; your controller method should be something as simple as `public function getProduct(Product $product){return view('...')->with('product', $product->load('images'));}`

Comment: @miken32 wow, this seems incredibly simple! By using this method I still assure that I am getting the product that matches the $url variable?

Comment: Yes by specifying the type in the method signature you are asking Laravel to do the lookup for you with [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding). (If `url` isn't your primary key you'll need to do some adjustment, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name) And the whole reason relationships are there is so that you don't have to do database lookups yourself.

Comment: @miken32 thank you so much! That's great! I will definitely look into that! Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

First change the below code in your frontendController

```
$imgs = ProductImage::where('product_id',$product->id)->get();
```

This will improve your query loading time.

Then in the below code

```
return view('frontend.product', ['product' => $product, 'products' => Product::all(), 'images' => $imgs ]);
```

why are you passing all the products to blade

```
'products' => Product::all(),
```

This is a bad idea, and it must be slowing down your page
only get what you need. calling everything in database is really not a good idea

Comment: @yadu siva das - in what way does that improve query loading time?

Comment: @newbie read this article https://dudi.dev/optimize-laravel-database-queries/